# JSON XPATH navigation in .NET

Tags: .net, json, xpath

in HTML, we can navigate using XPath.

Is there any library for JSON that uses the same idea? It's not nocessary to call it "XPath" because that's for HTML..

for example we have this JSON data

```
{
    "glossary": {
        "title": "example glossary",
        "GlossDiv": {
            "title": "S",
            "GlossList": {
                "GlossEntry": {
                    "ID": "SGML",
                    "SortAs": "SGML",
                    "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                    "Acronym": "SGML",
                    "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                    "GlossDef": {
                        "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
                        "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
                    },
                    "GlossSee": "markup"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

then if we want to get the ID of the first GlossEntry occurrence, then we could simply navigate to something like this
//GlossList/GlossEntry[0] and the result would have an object that has a lists of nodes in GlossEntry.

I found this JsonPath but it was written for JS and PHP
http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/

Comment: Take a look at XPath 3.1 and/or JSONiq.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

James Newton-King's Json.NET supports Stefan Gössner's JSONPath query syntax since its version 6.0 release 1.

See:

http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2014/02/01/json-net-6-0-release-1-%E2%80%93-jsonpath-and-f-support

I've also added JSONPath support to my own parser/deserializer earlier this year.

See:

https://github.com/ysharplanguage/FastJsonParser#JSONPath

Here are a few examples:

https://github.com/ysharplanguage/FastJsonParser/blob/master/JsonTest/ParserTests.cs#L343

'Hope this helps,